# Load binary .mx files from list of paths?

Tags: files-and-directories, dumpsave

I have several .mx files containing data saved to disk via `DumpSave`. I load a list of these files in my folder as

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
files = FileNames[All, ".\\data", Infinity];
```

Now I was trying to load them via

```
<< files[[1]]
```

or

```
<< ToExpression[files[[1]]]
```

or even

```
<< Evaluate[ToExpression[files[[1]]]]
```

none of which have worked.
How can I load an .mx file using a string of its path?

Comment: `files = FileNames["*.mx"]; Get[files[[1]]]`

Comment: Type `Get` insead of the shorthand `<<`, which treats its RHS as a string

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys!